# MYSQL Data Compare

Tags: sql, mysql, algorithm, sorting

Looking to compare today's temperature to yesterday's. If today's is higher than I want to return that row's id.

Table has 3 columns: `id`, `RecordDate`, and `temperature`.

Code works on small data sets but looking at a data set of 1400 seeing a 1% failure rate.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id

FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            id,
            recordDate, 
            recordDate - LAG(recordDate, 1) OVER (ORDER BY recordDate) AS diff, 
            temperature - LAG(temperature, 1) OVER (ORDER BY recordDate) AS dif

        FROM
            Weather
    ) AS t

WHERE
    dif > 0
    AND
    diff = 1

ORDER BY
    id ASC;
```

I expect this to sort the data by `recordDate`.

There are 2 conditions that must be met for the ID to be captured

1. Today's temperature is greather than yesterday (`dif > 0`)
2. and yesterday is in fact yesterday - there can only be a 1 day difference between rows (`diff = 1`)

Let me know how you'd improve this! Have been grinding for a while and could use the help.  Feel like there might be an easier way to do this even.

Comment: Why are you using `SELECT DISTINCT` here? And your outer-query has `ORDER BY  id ASC` which means it _won't_ sort by `recordDate` (unless the `id` column's values always monotonically increase with `recordDate`?)

Comment: You should choose more distinctive names than `diff` and `dif`...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "1% failure rate" - what do you mean by "failure"? You should also show us your full `CREATE TABLE` statements and some sample data - and the version of MySQL that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM (
    SELECT id,
           recordDate,
           temperature - LAG(temperature) OVER (ORDER BY recordDate) AS dif
    FROM Weather
) AS t
WHERE dif > 0
  AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM (recordDate - LAG(recordDate) OVER (ORDER BY recordDate))) = 1
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about performance, but what do you think of this?

```
SELECT w2.id from Weather w1 join Weather w2 
ON w2.temperature>w1.temperature 
AND date(w1.recordDate) = date(date_add(w2.recordDate, interval 1 day))
```